# Dynamically allocate memory for an int array converted to string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have an integer array that is dynamically allocated by the following:

```
int *ranArr(int size) {
    int *arr= malloc(size *sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = genRan(size);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

I want to dynamically allocate memory for a string that I will convert my integer array into and store it in the string:

```
        int *arrayCopy = ranArr(size);
        int arrayCopyLen = size;
        char *arrayString= (char*) malloc(size * sizeof(char));
        int index = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i< arrayCopyLen ; i++) {
            index += sprintf(&arrayString[index], "%d ,", arrayCopy[i]);
        }
        int arrayStringLen = strlen(arrayString)+1;
```

This works for array sizes around 1000 but when I set the size to 2000 or so it breaks and I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: What is `arrString`? it's not defined in your code

Comment: What's `genRan`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. This function takes an integer as parameter (typeof size) and returns an integer (typeof arr[i]). This function calculates something that is unimportant for the problem. The function name suggests some random number generation, but that's a guess.

Comment: @harper that is correct, it just generates a random number from 0 to size.

Comment: @ChrisTurner just made a type, corrected it in the edit!

Comment: Best to post true code rather than `char *arrayString= (char*) malloc(size * sizeof(char);`

Answer (score 3):

You're not allocating enough memory for your string.

Converting a single `int` to a string takes up up to 12 bytes, assuming an `int` is 32 bit.  For example, converting the value -2000000000 to a string needs 12 characters.  So you need at least `12 * size` bytes for your string, plus room for the `", "` characters and the null terminator.

Also, `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so no need to multiply by that.

```
char *arrayString = malloc(size * 14 + 1);   
// 14 = 12 bytes for a 32-bit int plus 2 bytes for ", "
```